# How can I run .exe external application with C++ and VS? And continue execute my C++ code?

Tags: c++

I solved it with command System(.. .exe);
And .exe application starts. But my VS C++ code stops and will continue only when I'll close started .exe application.
How can I continue my C++ code with opened and run .exe application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) your process, and start your application in the child process, or you can run a new [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) which will block untill your application terminates.

Comment: Is there method to run my app with same process with my C++ app? Or I should only run .exe in the another thread?

Comment: But fork will create copy of process, not run another exe...

Comment: Note that processes and threads are not the same. A fork will indeed create a copy of the process that you can use to run your app (with a system call like [`exec*`](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/exec.3.html) for linux).

Comment: I run my c++ code on the windows. Which way will be preffer for me?

Comment: `fork` does not exist on Windows (except, I guess, in WSL)